# Alamofire with append won't show data

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to append the data in the code here below. But it gives me an empty array back why?
Is it because i used this framework?

```
class func getDataByJson() -> Array<String> {

    let urlDb = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13259946/voorbeeld.json"

    //Werkt!

    var data: Array<String> = []

    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlDb)
        .responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
            //println(error)

            if let groups : AnyObject! = json {

                var group = groups["groups"] as NSArray

                for g in group {
                    data.append(g["name"] as NSString)
                    //println(data)
                }
                //println(data)
            }
           println(data)
        //return data
    }
    return data
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alamofire does everything asynchronously](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#usage). Instead of having `getDataByJson` return an array of strings, have it accept an additional `completionHandler` parameter that executes with the response data when the request finishes.